bash printf broken for floats
I have a bash script that gets battery information.
Here's part of it:
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full ]; then
  EF=$( echo $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full)/1000000|bc -l ) 
  [ -n "$EF" ] && printf "energy_full: %0.2f Wh\n" $EF
fi

This script worked for a long time then suddenly stopped working.
As an example, the $EF variable will contain 63.71100000000000000000 but the output of printf is a very long number nine lines long that starts with -7309889081043958068.
I tried using just %f but no luck. If I use %d it will print the integer before the decimal point but complain about an invalid number.
I'm using Debian testing.
GNU bash, version 5.2.32(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
With set -x
+ '[' -f /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full ']'
++ bc -l
+++ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full
++ echo 63711000/1000000
+ EF=63.71100000000000000000
+ '[' -n 63.71100000000000000000 ']'
+ printf 'energy_full: %0.2f Wh\n' 63.71100000000000000000
energy_full: -nan Wh

Just putting printf 'energy_full: %0.2f Wh\n' 63.711 into a script produces the same error.
I'm using British UK locale. The script used to work.
/bin/printf works, so I can use it as a workaround. Output: energy_full: 63.71 Wh

What version of bash is this? Also, add the set -x command to the beginning of the script to get a debug trace, and see what bash thinks the command it's running is.

I can't reproduce this with bash 5.2.15(1).  What the output from cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full?  The -f check suggest that you may  have a race condition so instead do energy_full=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full) and handle the error by checking $?

Please make a [mre]. I believe that should be as simple as ef=63.711; printf "%0.2f\n" $ef

What locale are you using? I'm using French and I had to change the period to a comma to get it to work as expected. Otherwise I got "line 4: printf: 63.711: invalid number" (translated). I'm using Bash 5.0.

There's almost never any reason to use $(echo $(command)). It's the same as just writing $(command)

Does printf '%0.2f' 63.71100000000000000000 return -nan?  It's different than the initial value you mentioned.  What about if you just use 63 (to @wjandrea's point)?

@Barmar They're piping echo into bc. That said, I'd use a here-string: bc -l <<< "$(cat ...)/1000000"

It doesn't answer the question but you could use bc to scale the number instead of the format string with echo "energy_full: $(echo 'scale=2; 63711000/1000000' | bc -l)"

Please add the output from locale.

This is a known bug, a patch is available here https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2024-08/msg00027.html

/bin/printf is probably the best work-around then.

@JFBonzo Don't forget LC_NUMERIC=C printf 'energy_full: %0.2f Wh\n' or your code will break on system with locale not using a dot as radix delimiter. For example your code break in fr_FR locale with: bash: printf: 63.71100000000000000000: nombre non valable

This is a known bug. A patch is available here: mail.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2024-08/msg00027.html
— comment by oguz ismail
